# Why is the System.Drawing.Image class defined as abstract while also defining methods that return it as a type?

Tags: .net, abstract-class

I'm trying to understand the design decision taken when the .NET framework creators designed the `System.Drawing.Image` class. It is abstract, and yet a lot of the heavy lifting is done directly with the `Image` class. It also defines two methods for directly creating an `Image` object, `Image.FromFile` and `Image.FromStream`.

I thought the purpose of an abstract class is to faciliate a way to define functionality that should only be inherited by child classes. It seems weird that an abstract class would actually define methods that return an instance of the abstract class.

Why was it implemeted this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an instance of the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). This pattern is prevalent throughout the .NET framework, another example is System.Net.WebRequest.Create, which can return a different subclass depending on the specified Uri.

The reasoning for the pattern is that a different subclass of Image, such as Bitmap, can be created depending on the image type.

Comment: @eulerfx: But the image class doesn't return subclasses, it actually returns an instance of itself . . .

Comment: The signature of the method specifies that an Image is returned, however the actual object instance that is returned will be a subclass of Image. You can verify this by starting a debug session, putting a break-point after an image instance is returned and looking into the variable to see the actual type.

Comment: @eulerfx: I don't understand how that could be. The return `Type` is `Image`, and there are no parameters or anything to tell it what subclass you want it to return. I think it really is returning an `Image` `Type`, not a subclass of `Image`. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: The subclass to be returned is decided by the Image class itself. You can create a subclass explicitly, for example var bmp = new Bitmap(@"c:\image.bmp");

Comment: @eulerfx: Ok I think I get it. It's decided based on the type of image that the actual file on disk (or the stream) is . . . I'm going to try this out.

Comment: Yup, you're right - it returned a `Bitmap` Type when I loaded a JPG. Thanks so much for helping me understand this!